# Vue.js code to update selection on screen

Tags: javascript, event-handling, vue.js

I have the following code snippet:

```
<tr>
    <td @click="changeTeam('WHU')">WHU</td>
    <td>20 Oct</td>
    <td @click="changeTeam('BHA')">BHA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td @click="changeTeam('CHE')">CHE</td>
    <td>21 Oct</td>
    <td>WAT</td>
</tr>
```

and the following VueJS method:

```
methods: {
            changeTeam(selection) {
                this.team = selection;
            }
         }
```

So as you can see, I'm calling this function and passing in the value in the table cell (i.e. `<td>` tag) to change a selection. This works for me, but is there a way I can capture the contents of the table cell, by means of some other method? Something a little more reusable or would this just be introducing extra overhead?

The table itself is the result of a dynamically generated page, so I'm not overly bothered about the apparent duplication.

Comment: If you have a couple of minutes, take the time to read [how to get the best value out of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) on our meta site: as it stands the question seems framed for a specific issue, the code boiled down to what amounts to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the surrounding context is missing: IOW you don't seem to be *looking for feedback on any & all aspects of the code* at all. That said this one-liner method seems entirely useless to me; I'd just inline it.

Comment: it was my first post here - thanks for the links and the comment. of course I was asking for feedback on the code. i was asking was there a way to capture the value of the table cell and now there are some suggestions. stack to the rescue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One technique would be to apply fundamentals of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) by adding a method to handle all clicks. For instance, an event listener could be added to the root element (or one if child its child nodes, like a `<table>`)

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
}
```

Then have the method accept the click event argument:

```
clickHandler(clickEvent){
```

That method could check if the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of the event was a table cell by checking the [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) attribute (for `TD`). To restrict to only certain table cells, add a [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute - e.g. *team*. If that class is found in the target element's [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), set the team property to the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the target.

```
clickHandler(clickEvent){
    const target = clickEvent.target;
    if (target.tagName == 'TD' && target.classList.contains('team')) {
        this.team = target.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

See a demonstration in the sample below. Notice how there is now a clean separation of the event handling logic (JS) and the markup for display (HTML).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    team: ''
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler(clickEvent) {
      const target = clickEvent.target;
      if (target.tagName == 'TD' && target.classList.contains('team')) {
        this.team = target.innerHTML;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Selected Team: {{ team }}</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="team">WHU</td>
      <td>20 Oct</td>
      <td class="team">BHA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="team">CHE</td>
      <td>21 Oct</td>
      <td>WAT</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. this is the kind of thing i was looking for. certainly takes the clutter out of my html. many thanks.